# NPE after restarting activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

After restarting activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

App is crashing without any references to my source code:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     java.lang.NullPointerException
     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchCollectViewAttributes(ViewGroup.java:980)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchCollectViewAttributes(ViewGroup.java:980)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchCollectViewAttributes(ViewGroup.java:980)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchCollectViewAttributes(ViewGroup.java:980)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1262)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2628)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It happened only few times on device. Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: You finish your Activity before starting the same ?

Comment: Should I remove 'finish' line?

Comment: What are your trying to do ? Can you explain why you need to restart your Activity ?

Comment: I have Activity which is using WebView to display its content. When device loses internet connection it's waiting for reconnection. I want to restart my Activity then to recreate all my objects.

Comment: Or a better way to do it would be if no internet is availabel attach a listener to the network and wait for a change and check if its available. Recreating the entire activity is a bad idea its too much overhead, limit to only WHAT you need to refresh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use `Activity#recreate` to do the job ?